# JQuery Elevate Zoom Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, plugins, zooming

Hey I have got a jQuery elevatezoom plugin in my .aspx page but it doesn't work.
After debugging, src image is visible as defined in  tag below but there is only a pointer doing nothing instead of lens and hence plugin functionality doesn't seem to work at all.
Here is my code.

```
<div>                                
    <img id="testimage" runat="server" src='~/Content/images/image1.jpeg'
                   data-zoom-image="~/Content/images/image2.jpeg" />
</div>
```

Here is my JS Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server"> 
<script src="Libraries/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/jquery.elevateZoom-2.5.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#testimage").elevateZoom({
                  zoomType: "lens",               
                  lensShape: "round",
                  lensSize: 200
           });
          }); 

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: and my project contains a master page as well.

Comment: The JS Code is under:

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server"> 
<script src="Libraries/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/jquery.elevateZoom-2.5.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
..
...
</script>
</asp:Content>

Comment: are you getting JavaScript error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I gave the `<div>` around `<img>` the "zoom-image" class and it made a world of difference.

```
<div class="zoom-image">                                
    <img id="testimage" runat="server" src='~/Content/images/image1.jpeg'
                   data-zoom-image="~/Content/images/image2.jpeg" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps?